# AutoMapper InternalDbSet`1 -> IQueryable`1 Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I receive the following exception:

> Mapping types:
>   InternalDbSet'1 -> IQueryable'1
>   Error mapping types.

My AssertConfigurationIsValid() returns valid, however once I run the following function in my transfer layer, the above exception is thrown.

```
public IQueryable<CategoryDTO> Categories
{
    get
    {
        return _mapper.Map<IQueryable<CategoryDTO>>(_context.Categories);
    }
}
```

This is the data access layer function which is called from the above function, where context.Categories is of type DbSet< Category >:

```
public IQueryable<Category> Categories => context.Categories.AsQueryable();
```

**CategoryDTO:**

```
[AutoMap(typeof(Category), ReverseMap = true)]
public class CategoryDTO
{
    public CategoryDTO()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }
}
```

**Category Entity:**

```
public class Category
{
    private ILazyLoader LazyLoader { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Category> _subcategories;
    private ICollection<Product> _products;
    private Category _parentCategory;

    public Category()
    {

    }

    public Category(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
    {
        LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentCategory")]
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category ParentCategory
    {
        get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _parentCategory);
        set => _parentCategory = value;
    }

    public ICollection<Category> Subcategories
    {
        get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _subcategories);
        set => _subcategories = value;
    }

    public ICollection<Product> Products
    {
        get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _products);
        set => _products = value;
    }

    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea where this issue is? The lack of an error in my assertion function has me lost.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu That did it! It's a tricky issue to catch with the lack of info in the AutoMapper exception thrown. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lucian commented, Queryable Extensions fixed my issue.

Here is the modified code:

```
public IQueryable<CategoryDTO> Categories
{
    get
    {
        //return _mapper.Map<IQueryable<CategoryDTO>>(_context.Categories);
        return _context.Categories.ProjectTo<CategoryDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```